# Styling contentEditable lists (<li>) with font-family, font-size, and color

Tags: javascript, css, html, contenteditable

I'm looking for a way to style lists so that they will use formatting set by the user while editing within a contentEditable element. Specifically, I want to be able to style the number/bullet in the same manner as the rest of the `<li>` content.

From the testing I've done, the browser never styles  `<li>` tags directly (which actually controls the style of the number/bullet) but always places a `<font>` tag (or `<span>` if `StyleWithCSS`) as the first child node, using it for the formatting. I've tried a few ideas already to get around this, but have not found success:

### 1. Apply styles to the `<li>` programmatically

Here I tried listening for 'DOMNodeInserted' and when an `<li>` tag was inserted into the DOM, I queried the current `fontName`, `fontSize`, and `foreColor` commands and applied them as an inline style on the `<li>`.

```
textarea.addEventListener('DOMNodeInserted', function (evt) {
    if (evt.target.nodeName === 'LI') {
        evt.target.style.color = queryCommandValue('foreColor');
        evt.target.style.fontFamily = queryCommandValue('fontName');
        evt.target.style.fontSize = queryCommandValue('fontSize');
    }
}, false);
```

Even when doing this, as soon as you begin typing in the list item, the browser tries to be "smart" and strips the styles from the `<li>`, placing them into a `<font>` (or `<span>`) tag.  :(

### 2. Create a rule for the styles to be inserted into the StyleSheet

Based off the attempt above, instead of writing the styles inline, I created a rule for them, gave the `<li>` node an ID, and inserted the rule into the stylesheet. Now the rule would govern the style of the `<li>`, and I could use the CSSOM to continually update any particular `<li>`'s styles.

This seemed to work very well (with a few bugs to solve for), however, it completely breaks the contentEditable undo stack. Since the undo command is only tied to `textContent` and other formatting commands, there is no way to "undo" the styles you are setting in the stylesheet. (At least not very intuitively, I've thought about how this might be done...)

### 3. Watch for changes in the `<li>`'s attributes and retain them

For this attempt, I made use of the newly-available MutationObserver [http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#mutationobserver](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#mutationobserve) available in DOM level 4. This observer can watch for changes in a node's attributes, which will be passed back in a MutationRecord. It can even hold the previous attribute values, including `style` values, so I could find out what was being removed and re-apply it.

```
var observer = new WebKitMutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
        if (mutation.target.nodeName === 'LI') {
            ...
        }
    })
});

observer.observe(document, {
    attributes: true,
    subtree: true,
    attributeOldValue: true
});
```

This still suffers from lack of undo support. You will undo other formatting changes but the `<li>`s will keep their styles.

Any novel ideas out there? Modern-browser only solutions welcomed as well. I'm aware that I could format my own HTML to use for lists but I'm trying to see if this can be done using the standard `insertOrderedList` and `insertUnorderedList` commands which use real list tags.

### ** Update Nov 7 2012 **

Doesn't look like anyone has solved this yet, here is an example JSFiddle to see what I'm describing: http://jsfiddle.net/8LyZR/. Just try to change the styles of bulleted or numbered lists.

For the project I am working on, we are using our own build of WebKit so we were able to fix this with a native change but I'm hoping there is a way (or will be a way) to do this directly with HTML/CSS/JS.

Comment: Can you provide any examples of what the HTML page would look like before and after as an image or just text? I'm having trouble visualizing what you're talking about.

Comment: I'm having this issue too.  contentEditable/execCommand always wants to surround text nodes with <font> or <span>.  Doesn't style the parent block element even if all text is selected within.  Annoying!

Comment: Here is an example rich text editor: http://jsfiddle.net/8LyZR/  You can try to style the list items in here to see what I'm describing.

Comment: Have you tried foregoing Content editable and tried listening to Keypress?

Comment: I've been pondering solutions to this, but have come across a difficulty in "expected" behavior. You want to style the `li`. But with content editable, because of inserting `font`, `b`, etc. tags, I can style _individual_ words _within_ the list. So I can make the 1st word bold, the 2nd blue, and a 3rd a font-size maximum. But you are saying that you would expect the bold, the blue, and the font-size to affect the whole list item, when that may not be the users intent. Any solution needs to distinguish if the entire list item is selected or just a portion of it, an additional challenge.

Comment: Yes, of course -- I'm not saying the `<li>` should be styled every time you change ANY of the content contained within. But if you, say, highlight the entire item, or you open a new list with certain font/size/color selected, the bullet/number should take the style. Just try it in MS Word or any other document editor. They all support this.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some interesting CSS trickery. http://jsfiddle.net/GZ3cv/

It basically relies on placing a psuedo-element `:before` on the inline tags, (which will inhereit the styles), and then attempting to position it on top of the original list bullets/numbers.

I can't decide if I would call this a solution, as it could grow impractical with all the different combinations of nested/inline tags (font,u,b,span,i).

But just playing around with font, size, color, and the list-type controls it seems like it could mimic what you are looking for with some obvious thorough tweaking involved.

I'm curious if this technique is plausible or just ridiculous :) Just throwin it out there..

Comment: Interesting approach and clever thinking. Just from playing with it for a while, I do unfortunately think there is an impractical (or even infinite) number of cases to solve for, especially when dealing with multiple `<li>`s which can contain other elements besides font/span.